# is the reset event cancelable

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, w3c

the  [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3) by the W3C in DOM Level 2 rule that the reset is not cancelable.

but when test it in chrome and firefox, the event's attribute cancelable is true,
and it can be cancel by calling e.preventDefault();

this is why?

Answer (score 1):

DOM Level 2, for the reset event, has been superseded by HTML5, [which says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-form-reset)

> When a form element form is reset, the user agent must fire a simple
>   **event named reset**, that bubbles and **is cancelable**, at form, and then,
>   if that event is not canceled, must invoke the reset algorithm of each
>   resettable element whose form owner is form.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on this and comment on which browsers support this? Seems like it might be a bad idea to rely on preventing the reset by using this method if it's recently changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any information on implementations. Being described for the first time in an HTML spec in HTML5 does not necessarily mean that it's new. The `contenteditable` attribute was implemented in IE6, but doesn't appear in an HTML spec until HTML5. The `embed` element is even older. Unfortunately, the best approach is just to test it in your target browsers.